# Static card with pending intent in timelinemanager

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to publish a static card into the `timelineManager` with a `pendingIntent`. However, after searching through the documentation, I can only find `pendingIntent` in LiveCard.

Can I check if I am missing something or is there any way to put `pendingIntent` inside a static card? I have managed to post a static card into the timeline, but I need to add interactions to this card.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to use `pendingIntent` on static card. this is a property of live card.
You can use `GestureDetector`, if you want to set menu on static card. Although you cannot update your static card, cause static card is STATIC.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to put a pending intent inside a static card.

There is no setAction for the [Card class](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/Card)

You can add a bit of interactivity, not through the GDK, but by using the MirrorAPI. Unfortunately, that interactivity was [not included in the GDK](https://developers.google.com/glass/design/ui/static-cards#characteristics) (no bundles, or pagination).

Comment: i guess so too. any reason given why not? =( not going to use MirrorAPI for an offline function...

Comment: I posted an issue on the project and it has been accepted =)

you can follow it here [link](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=320#makechanges)